# Android studio button has no onclick option error message box

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm currently learning to make apps in android studio. When I drag a button object into the activity_main.xml,it does not show me the "onclick" option under the "Declare Attributes".

The only error I'm getting is :

Couldn't resolve resource @color/teal_200
I dont think it has anything to do with my problem but still...

Any help would be appriciated,thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Add it via xml.

You'll find your button in there, declare onClick like this:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:onClick="doSomething"
    ... />
```

in your `MainActivity.java`:

```
public void doSomething(View v) {
    System.out.println("Clicked");
}
```

---

Nevertheless, it's better style to get the button by id and apply an `OnClickListener`:

```
Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener(() -> {
    System.out.println("Clicked");
});
```

---

The color-error is caused by a missing color in `res/values/colors.xml`.

You'll have to add your color there like this:

```
<resources>
    <color name="teal_200">#FF0033</color>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

make sure for when declaring color in your xml file you use

android:textcolor="@color/white" // for text color
android:backgroundTint="@color/black" // for button background color

also in your activitymain.java
I find it easier declaring your onclicks there

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button buttonnamegoeshere;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        buttonnamegoeshere = findViewById(R.id.buttonnamegoeshere);
        buttonnamegoeshere.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //button code goes hereenter code here
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This isn't quite the solution to the problem, but definitly a better alternative. Nevetheless, I would use a lambda expression to implement `View.OnClickListener`.